# Jquery function won't work if declared outside document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, scope

We have a simple Jquery function that serializes the inputs of a form and it is declared outside the `$(document).ready()`

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
     var formObj = {};
     var a = this.serializeArray();
     $.each(a, function() {
       if (formObj[this.name] !== undefined) {
         if (!formObj[this.name].push) {
           formObj[this.name] = [formObj[this.name]];
         }
         formObj[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
         formObj[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
     });
     return formObj;
   };
})( jQuery );
```

We have used this function many times and it is called on submit of a form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#test').submit(function(){
      var vars = $(this).serializeObject();
      console.log(vars);
      return false;
  });

});
```

This ALWAYS works but we are working a new project and we get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).serializeObject is not a function

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXESk/29/)

On the new project it only works if the serializeObject function is inside document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 (function( $ ){
   $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
     var formObj = {};
     var a = this.serializeArray();
     $.each(a, function() {
       if (formObj[this.name] !== undefined) {
         if (!formObj[this.name].push) {
           formObj[this.name] = [formObj[this.name]];
         }
         formObj[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
         formObj[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
     });
     return formObj;
   };
  })( jQuery );

  $('#test').submit(function(){
      var vars = $(this).serializeObject();
      console.log(vars);
      return false;
  });

});
```

We are using the same version of Jquery and no other external libraries.
Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The jsfiddle works for me with or without document.ready. Could you please show a demo that actually replicates the problem?

Comment: Are you sure jQuery isn't being included on the page more than once?

Comment: @JasonP you are a genius, we found another jquery down the code. Thanks! Add it as an answer so I can up-vote. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've included jQuery more than once, and here's what happens. This can "remove" plugins as well.

1. You include jQuery
2. You define your function and attach it to the jQuery function/object.
3. You include jQuery again. This new jQuery does NOT include the function you attached to the other instance of jQuery.